# Understanding why only finite sets have maximum/minimum

Tags: proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to understand intuitively why only finite sets are guaranteed to have a maximum and minimum. I believe, formally, the argument is that a finite set is closed (it contains all of its limit points, namely none), so it contains its supremum, which we therefore call a maximum, and similarly its infimum, which we therefore call its minimum.

If I have a set $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, I can surely take their maximum or minimum, but once I index by the natural numbers and try to take the max or min of $\{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, I can't guarantee that I can do this. Surely $[0,1]$ has a minimal and maximal element, $0$ and $1$, respectively. But $(0,1]$ has no minimal element, $[0,1)$ no maximal element.

What exactly is intrinsic to infinite sets that makes this the case? Is it as simple that they need not be closed? In the $(0,1]$ case, I would prove that it has no minimum by assuming for a contradiction that it has one, say $x$, and then averaging $0$ with $x$. I can always find such an element, no matter how small I make $x$, because the set is infinite. But that sounds a bit "hand-wavy" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct that only finite sets have a maximum and minimum. The condition for a set to have a maximum and minimum is [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), not being finite. Compact sets can intuitively be thought of as those that are closed and bounded, so all finite sets are compact. Simply being closed is not sufficient, because $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, but has neither a maximum, nor a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

As Sandejo pointed out, compactness also guarantees existence of a minimum or maximum. But it's not necessary. For instance, $[0,2]\backslash\{1\}$ is not compact but has a minimum and a maximum. There are no really useful equivalencies to the existence of both a maximum and minimum that I know of.

But about the second part of the question: what makes infinite sets different from finite ones? Well, finite ones can be covered by induction, while infinite ones can't. We can inductively prove that a weakly ordered set${}^\ast$ with $n$ elements, $n\in\mathbb N_+$, has a maximal element: For $n=1$ it's obviously true. The one given element is maximal. Then for $n+1$, we partition our set into two subsets, one containing a single element $M$, the other containing $n$ elements. The $n$ element set has a maximal element $N$. If $N\geq M$, then $N$ is maximal. Otherwise $M$ is maximal. This last step is not hard to do, and I leave it to you to formalize it, if you're interested in doing so.

Anyway, induction only allows us to prove things for finite $n$, so this approach fails for sets with an infinite number of elements. And as it turns out, it fails because the statement is simply not true for infinite weakly ordered sets.

${}^\ast$ a weakly ordered set is a set with an ordering relation $\leq$ such that $\leq$ is transitive and total (any two elements of the set are comparable, meaning that at least one of $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$ is true).